# Stored integer minutes in sql Server and display axis label in format hh:mm

Tags: c#, charts

I have in a database a field with the value in minutes (eg: 300)

I need to send those minutes to a chart and display it as hh:mm.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: in english please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the method:

`TimeSpan.FromMinutes(/*your integer from the database*/).ToString("HH:mm")`

you can find more information about the formatting here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

I hope it helps